# Do POP3 and IMAP Clash When Syncing the same account

Tags: email, imap, pop3

I am currently trying out IMAP with a few of my email accounts on both macs and pcs using Outlook. It seems to work fine (better on PC Outlook) to a certain extent, but there are a few issues which I cannot get to the bottom of.

Every now and again I get Send/Receive errors saying that Outlook cannot contact my server. Could this be because I have both POP and IMAP set up on the same account on several computers and they are therefore clashing when syncing with the server?

**UPDATE**
In other words, if I disable the account that is using POP, will the errors go?

Comment: Are you the host of the server? It seems more likely that the host is rate limiting connections or something similar. I'm not sure this is actually a programming question though? It might be better to use one of the other stack overflow sites?

Comment: I looked at the other stackoverflow sites and it seemed that there wasnt another one relevant to this sort of question, therefore I decided to go with SO. That is a good theory about the connection limits! Would you know where this would be set?

Comment: That really depends on you email server / provider I would guess, it could be within the mail server or within a firewall. I know I've seen messages from Google before though stating that it cannot connect then after a bit of a delay the reconnection is fine. If you're trying to reduce the connections client side, I don't actually know in outlook where this is stored but I can remember seeing a check frequency setting in the past I'm sure.

Comment: I will want to change the setting on the server. Not to worry, I will do some research and post what I find, if I do :-). Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; that would happen if the server is down (or buggy)

Comment: What sort of problems could it be on the server? Not enough memory? I am running a 1GB Linux and hosting around 15 websites with around 30 email accounts